# joomla jQuery - Cannot get jQuery working

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I'm trying to integrate the following in Joomla 3.8.11 (fresh installation) using Custom HTML module, JCE and Protostar.
I tried several things including using - `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` -
but unfortunately I can not get it working.

Can somebody help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Script:

```
    $(function(){
    $('.dragbox')
    .each(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).find('h2').addClass('collapse');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('h2').removeClass('collapse');
        })
        .find('h2').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        })
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
        })
        .end()
        .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: 'h2',
        cursor: 'move',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.4,
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.item).find('h2').click();
            var sortorder='';
            $('.column').each(function(){
                var itemorder=$(this).sortable('toArray');
                var columnId=$(this).attr('id');
                sortorder+=columnId+'='+itemorder.toString()+'&';
            });
            alert('SortOrder: '+sortorder);
            /*Pass sortorder variable to server using ajax to save state*/
        }
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
```

Html

```
<div class="column" id="column1">
    <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >
        <h2>Handle 1</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <!-- Panel Content Here --> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="item2" >
        <h2><span class="configure" ><a href="#" >Configure</a></span>Handle 2</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <!-- Panel Content Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="item3" >
        <h2>Handle 3</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <!-- Panel Content Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2" >
    <div class="dragbox" id="item4" >
        <h2>Handle 4</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <!-- Panel Content Here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="item5" >
        <h2>Handle 5</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <!--Panel Content Here--> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is some css to it but this is not causing any problems.

Comment: Check it in your browser's console for any errors. I think the jQuery in not found on your Project path, or may be you are adding jQuery after adding your script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the jQuery file on your web page. If not put his jQuery CDN link:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also check it in your browser's console for any errors. For this - in **chrome browser** press **F12 button then click the console tab**. I think the jQuery in not found on your Project path.

## ***See the image below:***

[image]

Comment: Hi, I added this in the custom html module:

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/panel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I use safari right now. I only can check with Chrome tonight. Thanks for the help already.